# Java: Access public member from a non-related class?

Tags: java, class-design

The following Java code is a stripped down example of the code I need. My question is, how do I access someInt from inside class Second? Note that Second implements another class, so I can not just pass someInt in.

```
package test1;

public class First {
    public int someInt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First x = new First();
    }

    public First(){
        someInt = 9;
        Second y = new Second();
    }
}


class Second implements xyz{
    public Second(){}

    public void doSomething(){
        someInt = 10; // On this line, the question lies.
        System.out.println(someInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework? If so, you should add that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `First`'s `someInt` field in `Second` because `Second` isn't an inner class of `First`. The changes below would fix your problem.

```
package test1;

public class First {
    public int someInt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First x = new First();
    }

    public First(){
        someInt = 9;
        Second y = new Second();
    }

    class Second {
        public Second(){
            someInt = 10;
            System.out.println(someInt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but why can't we creat an instance of the first class and acces the public variables, in this case someInt ??

Comment: You can if you like :) . To do that, you'd need to make additional changes to the code. In the original code, `Second` has no reference to `First`, so you'd either need to pass in a reference to the constructor (like `new Second(this)`, in `First`), or make `someInt` static in `First` and reference it in `Second` as `First.someInt`.

Comment: yeh we could do that as well :) lot of ways to do tat actually :P

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the field in `First` (and not create a new one in `Second`), you need to pass a reference to the instance of `First` when you create the instance of `Second`.

```
        Second y = new Second(this);
    }
}


class Second {
    public Second(First f){
        f.someInt = 10;
```

In the terms of your question, "Access public member from a non-related class", the problem is solved by creating a relation. If that isn't allowed, this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a public member follows the same syntax rules as accessing a public method (just without the brackets)

But having a public member in a class is usually not a good idea

Comment: is there any potential risk in doing that way (having public variables inside a class)? what are the other ways we an adopt to avoid this problem ?

Comment: If you need to expose properties to "the outside" this is usually done using a getXXX() method that returns the value. That way you shield the internal implementation. Read up on "encapsulation"

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way would be to

1) instantiate First

```
First f = new First()
```

2) access it directly because you made the instance variable someInt public

```
f.someInt = 10
```

A better way would be to provide accessors for someInt in First, and do it that way.

```
First f = new First();
f.setSomeInt( 10 );
...
int x = f.getSomeInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your second class, you must have a first class object. Create that object in your second class, then you will be able to access someInt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to an *instance* of `First` since `someInt` is not static.